# Kinect-based object Tracking

Tags: image-processing, kinect, video-processing, kinect-sdk, openkinect

I'm a beginner in Kinect development, trying to develop a real-time object tracker using openCV-Kinect on python, which will find me the X- and Y-coordinates of the object using the Camshift algorithm &  Z-coordinates by somehow using the Depth Stream of the Kinect. Is there a way to directly access the depth value of every pixel?

Answer (score 0):

Open www.google.com

Enter "kinect depth stream"

Click first result: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131028.aspx

Read line three:

> Each frame of the depth data stream is made up of pixels that contain
>   the distance (in millimeters) from the camera plane to the nearest
>   object.

Look around for 2 seconds and find the link **Getting and Displaying Depth Data**: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131029.aspx

Read the detailed explaination including code examples...